# CSS and Javascript manipulation

Tags: javascript

Hi guys im having trouble solving this question[image]

I have no idea what to do im so lost.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I posted a fighting-chance for you though I'm not going to do your homework for you either. If you really want to prove you're dedicated to learning later on post your own answer and show others how you solved the problems. You can view the JavaScript Documentation on the link in my profile for a lot of simple functions you can use (you don't need to copy everything, just the functions that will help you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make this as dead-simple as I can while requiring you to do some work:

1. Use Firefox to make this simple.
2. Right-click and press `q` to inspect the left element with all the text.
3. Does the element have an `id` attribute? E.g. `<textarea id="example_id">`?
4. Press Ctrl + Shift + k to bring up the developer console or click on the menu.
5. If the `id` is `example_id` then type `document.getElementById('example_id')` and press Enter to *reference the element*. If it does *not* have an `id` attribute right-click on the element containing the text and "Add attribute" and type `id="example_id"` and then press Enter.
6. Now type `document.getElementById('example_id').textContent` if it is *not a form* or if it is a form type `document.getElementById('example_id').value`.
7. Using whichever one above worked append `.split(';');` e.g. `document.getElementById('example_id').textContent.split(';')` (or `value` instead of `textContent`).
8. Now you need to assign your first set to a variable: `var a = document.getElementById('example_id').textContent.split(';')`.
9. Before you can create your second set you need to iterate over the first: `for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {console.log(a[i];}`.

In the browser you can usually click on things so if you simply type in `var a = 'string 234'.` the period will show you what commands will be available to this *string object*.

I can't sit here all night and do your homework for you though I do hope that I've provided enough to give you a fighting chance. I realize that yeah some students are lazy though at the same time a lot of classes are *not* properly taught, basic concepts are often expressed in a confusing / convoluted fashion.

You can absolutely accomplish amazing things with code to help people because that is the point of code at the end of the day. You're basically using code to take data and transform it in to a different form that is easier to work with subjective to the context.

In the future when posting show what you have attempted otherwise the (excessively) less-forgiving will kill your question outright. Good luck!